# How to delete one value from array php

Tags: php

**Hello**, I have this code and I want to correct it **because it deletes all same value and I want to delete one value**

```
            $rows = "944,1001,1001,3946";
            $sesto = explode(",",$rows);
            $arr = array_diff($sesto,array(1001));
            $comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
            echo $comma_separated;
```

i want to be **944,1001,3946**

Comment: use array_unique($array)

Comment: Are you simply looking to get all unique values?

Comment: @AlamDarji i want to delete specific value like if i want delete 944 i cant use array_unique

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no I want to delete specific value like if I choose to delete 944 it will be 1001,1001,3946 and if I choose 1001 it will be944,1001,3946

Comment: So if you have `$rows = "1001,944,1001,1001,1001,3946,3946,1001";` and want `1001` removed then should it be removed just once? Should it be removed all but once? Should the first occurrence remain in existence, or the last, or some middle occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the index of the first match and then use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove it:

```
$rows = "944,1001,1001,3946";
$arr = explode(",",$rows);
array_splice($arr, array_search(1001, $arr), 1);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
echo $comma_separated;
```

Note that this assumes that the element exists in the array. If you try to delete an element that doesn't exist it will delete the first element instead. If you do not want that behaviour use this to make sure it found an element before deleting:

```
$rows = "944,1001,1001,3946";
$arr = explode(",",$rows);

$index = array_search(1001, $arr);
if ( $index !== false ) 
    array_splice($arr, $index, 1);

$comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: @EXP I just realized that this assumes the element exists, and behaves weird if it doesn't (deletes the first element instead of doing nothing).

Comment: @EXP I added an alternative that does not modify the array if you try to delete an element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to remove a value from an array, but it looks like you really need to remove it from a string. You start with a string, then turn it back into a string at the end before output. If that's really the situation, you can use `preg_replace` to remove the value directly from the string without converting back and forth to array.

```
$value = 1001;
$rows = preg_replace("/\b{$value},|,{$value}$/", '', $rows, 1);
echo $rows;
```

I'm not a regex expert, so there's probably a better way to write the regex, but this works for your example, and the general idea is the same even if the specific regex can be optimized.

The last argument limits the replacements to 1.

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity `array_unique($sesto)`

for more info https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_unique.php

Hope this helps.